# REGEX to extract part of link

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to scrape some auction IDs off an auction site page. The page is [here](http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categorylistings.aspx?mcatpath=sports%2Fcycling%2Fmountain-bikes%2Ffull-suspension&page=2&sort_order=default&rptpath=5-380-50-7145-)

For the page I am interested in, there are approximately 60 auction ids. An auctionID is preceded by a dash, consists of 10 digits, and terminates before a `.htm`.  For example in the link below the ID would be `0133346952`

```
<a href="/sports/cycling/mountain-bikes/full-suspension/auction-1033346952.htm" class="tile-2">
```

I have got as far as extracting ALL links from, by identifying "a" tags. This code is at the bottom of the page.

Based on my limited knowledge, I would say REGEX should be the right way to solve this. I was thinking REGEX something like :

```
-...........htm
```

However, I am failing to successfully integrate the regex into the code. I would have though something like

```
for links in soup.find_all('-...........htm'):
```

would have done the trick, but obviously not.

How can I fix this code?

```
import bs4
import requests
import re
res = requests.get('http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categorylistings.aspx?mcatpath=sports%2fcycling%2fmountain-bikes%2ffull-suspension&page=2&sort_order=default&rptpath=5-380-50-7145-')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for links in soup.find_all('-...........htm'):
    print (links.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that works:

```
for links in soup.find_all(href=re.compile("auction-[0-9]{10}.htm")):
    h = links.get('href')
    m = re.search("auction-([0-9]{10}).htm", h)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

First you need a regex to extract the `href`. Then you need a capture regex to extract the id.

Comment: How about making the digit string 10 digits like OP says. `[0-9]{10}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in a [regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) object to `find_all()` you are
just handing in a string that you want to use as the pattern for a regex.

To learn and debug this kind of stuff, it is useful to cache the data from the site until things work:

```
import bs4
import requests
import re
import os

# don't want to download while experimenting
tmp_file = 'data.html'

if True and os.path.exists('data.html'):   # switch True to false in production
    with open(tmp_file) as fp:
        data = fp.read()
else:
    res = requests.get('http://www.trademe.co.nz/browse/categorylistings.aspx?mcatpath=sports%2fcycling%2fmountain-bikes%2ffull-suspension&page=2&sort_order=default&rptpath=5-380-50-7145-')
    res.raise_for_status()
    data = res.text
    with open(tmp_file, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write(data)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
# and start experimenting with your regular expressions
regex = re.compile('...........htm')
for links in soup.find_all(regex):
    print (links.get('href'))
# the above doesn't find anything, you need to search the hrefs
print('try again')
for links in soup.find_all(href=regex):
    print (links.get('href'))
```

And once you get some matches you can improve on your regex pattern, using more sophisticated techniques, but that is in my exerience less important than starting with right "framework" for trying things out quickly (without waiting for a download on every code change tested).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'-(\d{10})\.htm')
print(p.search('<a href="/sports/cycling/mountain-bikes/full-suspension/auction-1033346952.htm" class="tile-2">'))
res = p.search('<a href="/sports/cycling/mountain-bikes/full-suspension/auction-1033346952.htm" class="tile-2">')
print(res.group(1))
```

`-(\d{10})\.htm` means that you want a dash, 10 digits and `.htm`. What is more, these 10 digits are in capturing group, so you can extract them later.

You search for this pattern, and after that you have two groups: one with whole pattern, and one with capturing group (only 10 digits).

Answer (score 0):

in python you can do:

```
import re
text = """<a href="/sports/cycling/mountain-bikes/full-suspension/auction-1033346952.htm" class="tile-2">"""
p = re.compile(r'(?<=<a\shref=").*?(?=")')
re.findall(p,text) ## ['/sports/cycling/mountain-bikes/full-suspension/auction-1033346952.htm']
```

Comment: AFAIK `findall` has been deprecated in favour of `find_all` in 2012.

Comment: its still called .findall according to 3.5.1 documentation. i think you are thinking of soup.find_all() which finds all elements of a certain tag. i asnwered this from a regex point of view, not beautiful soup. but still one can run re.search on each soup.find_all() element, with the pattern and still get the results

Comment: I consider the 3.5.1 docs irrelevant if the OP is obviously working with BeatifulSoup4 (`import bs4`)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple; you don't need regex. Let `s` be your string (I couldn't put the whole line here due to my not knowing how to handle the wrap around.)

```
s = '<a href="....../auction-1033346952.htm......>'
i = s.find('auction-')
j = s[i+8:i+18]
print j
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest way wo regexes

```
>>> s='<a href="/sports/cycling/mountain-bikes/full-suspension/auction-1033346952.htm" class="tile-2">'
>>> s.split('.htm')[0].split('-')[-1]
'1033346952'
```